# Finding Degrees of Freedom For Chi Squared Test proportions

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

There's a litany of other questions[previously posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) about finding df during a GOF test but I still struggle to understand it.

I know that a way of thinking of df is to do (number of categorical variables)-1=df. But for a normal distribution df = n-3 and for Poisson it's n-2 and i wasn't sure what df to use if I were using GOF test for proportions. So essentially I was wondering how do we deduce what df we should use for each model that we are testing?